# Ruby On Rails --After filling details and saving the form I'm getting Connection Reset Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a form for collection company details . If the form details are saved , it is

redirected to next page . My problem is after clicking saving button  it is redirecting but diplaying ***"connection was reset "***

my **routes.rb** file

```
 get 'companies/new'
 match 'companies/create' => 'companies#create' , :as => "create_companies_path" , :via => "post"
 match 'companies/upload' => 'companies#upload'
 resources :companiesde
```

my latest development log details

```
     Started POST "/companies/create" for at 2013-05-09 11:24:02 +0530
Processing by CompaniesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"J7AnRNRpqHGvPTzc1qlbn9/X5ITA8T0HaibAgqD+qrI=", "companies"=>{"f_name"=>"Ghayathri", "l_name"=>"Angamuthu", "email"=>"aghayathri@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "c_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "c_name"=>"FixNix", "location"=>"Chennai", "m_number"=>"9566735440", "isms"=>"Yes", "no_empl"=>"1", "date_started(1i)"=>"2013", "date_started(2i)"=>"5", "date_started(3i)"=>"9", "modules_list"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Save Companies"}
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO `companies` (`c_name`, `c_password`, `created_at`, `date_started`, `email`, `f_name`, `isms`, `l_name`, `location`, `m_number`, `modules_list`, `no_empl`, `password`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, '2013-05-09 05:54:02', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2013-05-09 05:54:02')[0m
  [1m[35m (42.6ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  COMMIT
Redirected to companies/create
Completed 302 Found in 48ms (ActiveRecord: 43.2ms)
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
```

my controller code :

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @companies = Companies.new 
  end

  def create 
    @companies = Companies.create(params[:id])
    if @companies.save 
        redirect_to 'companies/create'
    end
  end
end
```

My form look:

```
<%= form_for :companies, :url => {:action => "create"} , :method => "post" do |f| %>
Enter your Company Details :
<br />
<br />
<%= label_tag(:f_name, "First Name:") %>
<%= f.text_field(:f_name) %>
<br />
<br />
<%= label_tag(:l_name, "Last Name:") %>
<%= f.text_field(:l_name) %>
<br />
<br />
<%= label_tag(:email , "Email:") %>
<%= f.email_field(:email) %>
<br />
<br />
<%= label_tag(:password , "Password") %>
<%= f.password_field(:password) %>
<br />
<br />
<%= label_tag(:c_password , "Confirm Password") %>
<%= f.password_field(:c_password) %>
<br />
<br />
<%= label_tag(:c_name , "Company Name:") %>
<%= f.text_field(:c_name) %>
<br />
<br />
<%= label_tag(:location , "Location:") %>
<%= f.text_field(:location )%>
<br />
<br />
<%= label_tag(:m_number , "Mobile number") %>
<%= f.telephone_field(:m_number) %>
<br />
<br />
Do You have ISMS implemented ?
<%= f.radio_button(:isms , "Yes" )%>
<%= f.radio_button(:isms , "No") %>
<br />
<br />
<%= label_tag(:no_empl , "No of Employees") %>
<%= f.select(:no_empl ,options_for_select([['> 10',1],['< 10',2],['<100',3]])) %>
<br />
<br />
<%= label_tag(:date_started , "When do you start your organization:")%>

<%= f.date_select(:date_started) %>

<br />
<br />
<%= label_tag (:modules_list) %>
<%= f.select(:modules_list , options_for_select([['Audit Management',1],['Risk Management',2],['Policy Management',3]])) %>
<br />
<br />
<%= f.submit %>


<%end %>
```

Comment: Are you uploading a file? Perhaps the size is too big. Please post your development log.

Comment: I'm not uploading any thing I just tried it out,I'm not saving it to my database.

Comment: is that the full error message? Just "connection was reset"?

Comment: Are you redirecting in your controller? Post the controller code.

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed two things that are wrong with your code.

**First**, it looks like in your `routes.rb` file you're not using `:as =>` properly. When naming routes you don't need to include `_path`, rails adds that automatically. Here's the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes).

Your code reads:

```
match 'companies/create' => 'companies#create' , :as => "create_companies_path" , :via => "post"
```

It should read something like this:

```
match 'companies/create' => 'companies#create' , :as => :create_companies , :via => :post
```

---

**Second**, you're using `redirect_to` in your controller improperly. For the redirect to work properly, you need to supply a fully qualified URL. Rails has a convention for generating URLs from `*_path`. In your case I would use something like this:

```
redirect_to create_companies_path
```

Here are [some more examples](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to) of what you can do with `redirect_to`:

```
redirect_to :action => "show", :id => 5
redirect_to post
redirect_to "http://www.rubyonrails.org"
redirect_to "/images/screenshot.jpg"
redirect_to articles_url
```

Comment: I have changed my redirect_to 'companies/create' into redirect_to 'create_companies' but then i'm getting the same error

Comment: That's still incorrect. If you're going to pass in a string it needs to be either an absolute url `http://www.rubyonrails.org` or a relative url `/images/screenshot.jpg`.

Comment: run `rake routes`. That will show you the url you can specify for `companies#create`.

Comment: company_create POST   /companies/:company_id/create(.:format) companies#create
is my rake routes

Comment: You need to pass in an object so it know's what ID to put in the url. Try `redirect_to company_create_path(@companies)` within your controller.

Comment: I'm getting Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/companies/91/create"

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

Comment: Wait, why are you redirecting to a create page.. you shouldn't need to do that. You should redirect to the show page after `@companies.save` is successful. It should be something like `redirect_to companies_path(@companies)`